# Make 'ifup eth0' permanently UP

Tags: raspbian

how do I make 'ifup eth0' permanently UP even I after restarting the RaspberryPi

Comment: I would have thought that `eth0` is `up` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use the following content in `/etc/network/interfaces` if you want to get a static IP (adapt the network definitions to your local environment)

```
auto lo
auto eth0

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to make sure it comes up every boot your `/etc/network/interfaces` file should look like this:

```
auto lo
auto eth0

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```